# TCPDF - poder juntar pdfs de distintas carpetas

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, tcpdf

He buscado la manera, pero no sé si han logrado poder generar un botón que llame a una función de TCPDF para que traiga distintos PDFs ya cargados en el sistema y los una en un solo PDF.

Esto es en PHP, con TCPDF y MYsql

Saludos

Comment: Qué tipo de botón? Qué función de TCPDF has considerado para ésto? A qué te refieres con PDF ya cargados en el sistema? Cuál sistema? Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes

Comment: yo tengo un boton en el elevador pero jamas se me habia ocurrido usarlo para que de ese boton salga un PDF... tampo me funciona para eso del boton de la licuadora ... alguien sabe como hacerlo ...???

Comment: disculpen que haya sido todo a la rápida, lo que sucede es que en un sistema que desarrollé en php, guardo distintos pdf que son cargado por los usuarios, quería saber si han logrado desarrollar una función que llame a los pdfs y los una dentro de un mismo documento.

Comment: Te dejo estas tres ligas, que hacen referencia a la manipulacion de los pdfs con php y librerias o PHP al natural, espero te sirvan de algo...https://parzibyte.me/blog/2019/02/04/unir-combinar-archivos-pdf-php-libmergepdf/   ,  https://www.iteramos.com/pregunta/81130/combinar-archivos-pdf-con-php , https://www.lawebdelprogramador.com/codigo/PHP/3326-Unir-varios-PDFs-monopagina-en-uno-multipagina.html  antes que cierren la pregunta.  Saludos

Comment: @Cesarin Muchisimas Gracias

Comment: @Francisco Barriga De nada, espero que te sirvan, traen material muy interesante. Y pues en lo que se pueda colaborar.  Saludos